# most concise code to create an array with method-generated values

Tags: ruby

I want to create an array with n values that are generated by calling method. The array index is irrelevant when generating the values.

This is where I am at:

```
(1..2).map { Random.rand(10) }
```

I like the idea of doing something like `2.times { Random.rand(10) }`, but this does not return an array. Is there any way that is more concise?

Comment: For starters: don't do tags in the title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-c-new) accepts a block:

```
Array.new(2) { rand(10) } #=> [5, 2]
```

Comment: That's great! I don't think we can do better than this.

Comment: Not the shortest code, but probably the most concise.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this, using the fact that `times` without block returns [`Enumerator`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html):

```
2.times.map { rand(10) }
```

Comment: Good to know! Dziekuje :)